# Saving Worksheet to New Workbook and End Macro if Canceled

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on this for over 3 hours and cannot figure it out.
I am wanting to save a worksheet to a new workbook. All works great unless the "cancel" button is chosen in the dialog box. The message "Want to save your changes" displays and then need to choose the "Don't Save". I do no want for this dialog box to appear. In other words, exit the macro if the "cancel" button is chosen.
Here is my code:

```
Sub SU_SaveAsWorksheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call SU_TransferToExcel

Dim wb, wbnew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filename As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CE_Excel") 'Name of sheet you are copying

filename = Sheet15.Range("K5") & ".xlsx"

'adds new workbook
Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
wb.Activate

'copies sheet to new workbook
  wb.Sheets("CE_Excel").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       wbnew.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Save as dialog box to save as excel file
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show filename

wbnew.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The .Show method is likely a function that returns a value you can use to determine whether it was cancelled or not. IIRC it returns a Boolean (`False`) when cancelled, so you can check the `VarType` of the result; if it's a `vbBoolean` you know it was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't turn on the DisplayAlerts or turn it off again before the Close e.g.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbnew.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```